# iOS - Pubnub SDK experiencing a delay to get publish call back

Tags: ios, swift, delay, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I created a sample iOS application using swift to publish and subscribe real-time messages, used Pubnub SDK for that. Publishing device also subscribing the publishing channel.I am facing some latency issue(around 1.5 seconds) to get the published message on subscriber callback. This latency occurs only in two scenarios.

1. Publishing first message after connecting the pubnub client.
2. Publishing a new message after 20+ seconds of idle time.(Idle time means I am not publishing any messages during this time).

Both cases I am getting 1.5 seconds latency. 
But if I am publishing messages continuously there is no latency issue and I am getting only 0.2 seconds latency.

I am using Pubnub SDK version - 4.7.2, and running on iOS devices with OS version 9 and above.

This issue is faced while testing in India and Australia, I didn't get chance to test in other countries.

I am attaching my code where I am using pubnub client and how I am publishing messages and subscribing channel.

```
fileprivate let publishKey = "pub-c-2ca0-redacted"
fileprivate let subscribeKey = "sub-c-91bd-redacted"

extension Date {

    static var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSSSz"
        return dateFormatter
    } ()

    var stringFormat: String {
        return Date.formatter.string(from: self)
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var client : PubNub?
    let publishQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Publish Queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [.concurrent])
    let callbackQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "PubNubCallbackQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [.concurrent])



    @IBAction func publish(_ sender: Any) {
        // We NEED to get the text field contents in the main thread or we violate UIKit API
        let publishStep0 = Date()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let publishStep1 = Date()
            let publishText = self.textField.text ?? "default"
            self.publishQueue.async {
                let publishStep2 = Date()
                self.client?.publish(publishText, toChannel: "my_channel1",
                                     compressed: false, withCompletion: { (status) in
                                        let publishStep3 = Date()
                                        print("****** \(#function) publish steps ******")
                                        print("Step 1: \(#function) => Tap Button: \(publishStep0.stringFormat)")
                                        print("Step 1: \(#function) => Get Text from TextField \(publishStep1.stringFormat)")
                                        print("Step 2: \(#function) => Initiate Publish \(publishStep2.stringFormat)")
                                        print("Step 3: \(#function) => Receive Publish Callback \(publishStep3.stringFormat)")
                                        print("****************************************")
                                        if !status.isError {
                                        }
                                        else{

                                        }
                })
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let config = PNConfiguration(publishKey: publishKey, subscribeKey: subscribeKey)
        config.stripMobilePayload = false
        self.client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(config, callbackQueue: callbackQueue)
        self.client?.logger.enabled = true
        self.client?.logger.setLogLevel(PNLogLevel.PNVerboseLogLevel.rawValue)
        // optionally add the app delegate as a listener, or anything else
        // View Controllers should get the client from the App Delegate
        // and add themselves as listeners if they are interested in
        // stream events (subscribe, presence, status)
        self.client?.addListener(self)
        self.client?.subscribeToChannels(["my_channel1"], withPresence: false)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

// MARK: - PNObjectEventListener
extension ViewController: PNObjectEventListener {

    func client(_ client: PubNub, didReceive status: PNStatus) {

        print("Status \(status.stringifiedCategory()) at time: \(Date().stringFormat)")
    }

    func client(_ client: PubNub, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Message received $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
            print("message: \(message.debugDescription)")
            print("time: \(Date().stringFormat)")
            print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
//            self.label.text = self.label.text?.appending(",\(message.data.message!) ") // this is bad because there might not initially be text, what is the behavior of appending when the label has no text?
            let currentText = self.label.text ?? ""
            let appendingText = message.data.message ?? "No text in message"
            self.label.text = currentText.appending(",\(appendingText)")
            self.label.setNeedsLayout() // don't forget to tell the view engine to update the label
        }

    }

    func client(_ client: PubNub, didReceivePresenceEvent event: PNPresenceEventResult) {
        // This most likely won't be used here, but in any relevant view controllers
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you enable PubNub Swift SDK client logging, reproduce and send logs to PubNub support (since it will include you pub/sub keys which I redacted above (security risk).

Comment: If you do send logs to PubNub Support, please include link to this thread so that we can post back any relevant answers.

Comment: Can you provide status on this? Did you send to support or did you find resolution (if so, post back here, please)?

Comment: When pubnub publishing, the first connect is taking time because it has to first hit pubnub, establish a connection (ssl handhsake), and then push data. The subsequent publishes happen way faster because the connection is already established. Same when the app is idle for a while. What you can do is to make any other pubnub call in the meantime to prevent these delays from happening (it can be any pubnub call).
Or set TLSEnabled tp false.

Comment: Interesting, we do not have anyone complaining of delays like this. I would not recommend disabling TLS either. In fact, iOS apps require it or you have to declare an exception in your app's plist.